# Small detail in proof of Borsuk-Ulam theorem.

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

I’m reading the following proof.

> **Corollary B13.2.** There is no odd map $S^{m} \rightarrow S^{m-1}$.
>
> **Theorem $\mathbf{B 1 3 . 3}$ (Borsuk-Ulam Theorem).** Given any continuous map $f: \mathbb{S}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$, there exists a pair of antipodal points $\pm x \in \mathbb{S}^{m}$ with $f(x)=f(-x)$.
>
> **Proof.** If there is no such $x$, we can set
> $$
> g(x):=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{\|f(x)-f(-x)\|}
> $$
> giving an odd map $g: \mathbb{S}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^{m-1}$. This contradicts the previous corollary.

One small detail that I don’t get is how we can conclude that the image of $g$ is $\mathbb{S}^{m-1}$. Some elaboration would be appreciated.

Comment: $\|g(x)\|=1$.  That is it!

Comment: $\|au\|=a\|u\|$ for $a\geq 0$.

Comment: Say we are talking about a map $g$ from the unit $2$-sphere. I can see that the images of $g$ have norm $1$. But how do I know they all lie in a circle?

Comment: They have norm 1 so they lie on the sphere. That is the definition of the sphere. (in case $m=2$ the sphere is the circle).

Comment: I read the statement in the proof as saying the images of $g(\mathbb{S}^{m-1})$ all lie in just $\bf{\text{one}}$ $\mathbb{S}^{m-1}$. Why can’t a point of $\mathbb{S}^{m-1}$ be mapped to a vector of norm $1$, but on a different $\mathbb{S}^{m-1}$?

Comment: What do you mean by a different $S^{m-1}$? You have a map $g:S^m\to R^m$ and you just checked that its image sits inside the one and only canonically chosen sphere $S^{m-1}\subseteq R^{m}$ which is defined by the "norm=1" condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that $f$ is a map *into* $S^{m-1}$, as indicated by the fact that $||f(x)||=1$ for any $x$ and $f(x)\in\Bbb R^m$.